# 2 Different servers for the same domain

Tags: domain

I have a system which i can configure as webserver, but not sure about the downtime. Can i have the same domain on 2 servers of 2 different geographical locations. I sync  the site in 2 servers.

If i use the the Nameserver 1 from my first server and Nameserver 2 from second server in the domain setting. if the Server 1 is not available, will the site from server 2 load?

Thanks & Regards,
Satya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, question is how and why.

1) If you have direct control over the domain nameservers, you can for instance choose lbnamed as your DNS server, which will do load balancing.

2) If you don't, most providers will still let you do round robin balancing, however, it will merely distribute load without providing for any high availability.

3) Finally, some DNS providers offer some load balancing services (for a fee), for instance UltraDNS.

Comment: Hi can i make the load balancing based on the geographic location of the visitor?